# Model based bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, inference, model, bias

I would like to understand how model based bootstrap works. Am I right that this is a technique that allows for the derivation of Inference in cases where the model is too complicated for analytical derivations?

So if my model assumes that my response $Y$ comes from a distribtion function $f_Y(y,\theta)$ and I am able to estimate $\theta$ (lets call the estimator $\hat{\theta}$), for example via Maximum Likelihood, then model based bootstrap would work like:

1) Draw $s$ samples $\tilde{Y}=\{\tilde{Y}_1,...,\tilde{Y}_s\}$ from $f_Y(y,\hat{\theta})$

2) Re-Estimate $\theta$ $s$ times, based on the sample $\tilde{Y}$, collect this estimators in $\tilde{\theta}=\{\tilde{\theta}_1,...,\tilde{\theta}_s\}$

3) Take the empirical variance (or its squareroot) of the collection $\tilde{\theta}$ in order to make inference about $\hat{\theta}$.

Seems really easy (and somehow baysian). Is there some twist with this approach?

I see that the approach is very sensitive to the choosen estimator. What about a situation where we have a biased estimator and the mean of the sample $\tilde{\theta}$ deviates strongly from $\hat{\theta}$?

And what about models with covariates. Do we treat them as fixed in step 2)? Or do we simulate them based on an own model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know "Model based bootstrap" but, assuming you are using the same estimator for Step 2 and for  $\hat{\theta}$,  the 3-steps algorithm you give  corresponds to the [parametric bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Parametric_bootstrap) (for variance estimation) that is (asymptotically) valid under regularity conditions of your estimator. This approach is as accurate as the delta method.

Comment: Nice to know the thing I know as model based bootstrap is the same as parametric bootsrap.